# Download file and save it in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, isolatedstorage

I have following code in my Windows 8/RT app:

```
public static async Task<StorageFile> SaveAsync(Uri fileUri, StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);
            var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            var download = downloader.CreateDownload(fileUri, file); // here Exeption is fired
            var res = await download.StartAsync();
            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

ex.message: `Access denied`

Note:
`file` - it's a correct `StorageFile` (`ContentType=image/jpg`)
 `fileUri` - it's correct image uri
`folder` - it's correct storage folder.
 What I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found little mistake:
I forgot, that `fileUri` is Uri to local server. Just adding nested property to manifest fixed problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `folder` when you call the code?  You may need to add a capability in Package.appxmanifest to the appropriate folder (e.g. Pictures folder, Documents folder).

By default, the sandboxed nature of a Modern UI app means that it will have explicit access only to its own local folder (think about it like Isolated Storage).  In order to access other locations, your manifest file *must* declare that it needs to access those other locations.  The available locations are, however, quite limited.

If you use the Save File Picker, however, you have access to a larger range of locations in which to save your file.

Comment: folder(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder): Atr: Dirrectory, Display type: File Folder.. what else you want to know? In this folder I want to save not only images, but pdf's and other files.

Comment: @jimpanzer in Win8, is you want to, for example, access the documents folder, then you need to explicitly say so in the app manifest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx